# Can I specify to only match vectors that have one word using tsvectors?

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

I want to search for words in a tsvector only if they are the only words in the text. is there a way to do that? what about specifying that a word must be the last or the first word? The reason I'm using tsvector is that i need to match stemmed words.

**UPDATE:** sample data would be a table that contains three rows such as:

```
  id      |      text       |    ts_vector
---------------------------------------------
  1       |    eating       | -- this column holds vector data
          |                 |
  2       |    eating food  |
          |                 |
  3       |    eats         |
```

I want to be able to search for the word `eat` and only return the one with id = 1 and id = 3 but id 2 should be ignored. Query would look something like this:

`to_tsquery('english', 'eat') @@ tablename.ts_vector`

except this returns all three rows in this example as you know

Thanks!

Comment: share sample data and its output

Comment: updated the post!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE SUBSTRING(TEXT FROM 1 FOR 3)= 'EAT';
```

Comment: the problem here is that this will not work with stemmed words and tsvectors

Comment: did you mean you want to search for the pattern in the whole string not from the starting point?

Comment: no, I mean I want to use tsvectors in order to search for words stem. I have millions of rows with millions of possible patterns. some words will change shape when stemmed. I can't use substring or `=` operator